# Is there a way to delete an entire row and shift the cells up in xlwings?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, xlwings

If I wanted to delete an entire row and shift the cells up is there a way to do that? Below is a snippet of my loop which is iterating through the column and clearing the contents of the cell if it doesn't match my parameters. Is there a way rather than clearing just the cell in column A I could delete the whole row and shift up?

```
    for i in range(lastRow):
        i = i + 1
        if sheet.range('A' + str(i)).value != 'DLQ' or 'DLR':
            xw.Range('A' + str(i)).clear()
            continue
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: BigBen - if you're back to edit my post, numpy and pandas reaches a larger audience of people who also use xlwings since using numpy or pandas solely is incredibly unlikely, please leave my tags alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [delete()](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Range.delete) and specify the rows number(s) you want to delete in range():

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book(r"test.xlsx")

wb.sheets[0].range("2:2").delete()
```

This would delete row number 2.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thank you, @mouwsy!

Comment: For those who want to know how to shift up, the line of code @mouwsy provided would end up looking like ```wb.sheets[0].range('2:2').delete(shift='up')```